# What is the difference between requesting a shell separately or through PTY in SSH protocol?

Tags: linux, ssh, libssh

> What is the difference between requesting a shell separately or through PTY in SSH protocol?

I want to program a remote shell application using libssh.

To do this, I've the options between requesting a shell or requesting a shell through PTY. The documentation decribes the differences as interactive/non-interactive. However, I don't know the difference.

What approach should I choose to program a remote shell application using libssh? What are the pros/cons?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute some script and capture its output, it is not interactive.

Interactive script would be something that you would want to interact with. Some of the tools, such as `sudo` may require the interactive access by checking the TTY. Also inserting a password into command-line `ssh` requires interactive session. But running a script with PTY will send special control characters for PTY, which will modify the binary that you will transfer. This means it is not suitable for file transfers and so on.

That's all.

Comment: Isn't a PTY always interactive?

Comment: Well ... it depends how you define interactive. You can send and receive data even to non-interactive sctipts. But PTY basically adds some control characters to the flow, which might "mess up" your binary data transfers (which I forgot to mention in the initial answer).

Comment: Can you define interactive/non-interactive session in your answer? :-)

Comment: I tried the best with examples. Without knowing what you want to achieve.

Comment: What if I want to have a terminal session where the terminal remembers state, e,g., current directory. Does that require interactive?

Comment: No. It does not require interactive session. But it will not run in single "shell" and will not remember the working directory. If you want to modify working directory, you should put it in a single command.

Comment: what technique should I use to program a remote terminal session? How do I create a stateful shell s.t. the remote shell interaction is identical to a local shell?